# Utilização do método filter com Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Tenho a classe `Posicao` e nela tenho um atributo **`data: LocalDate`**.

Tenho um Array de `FaixaPreco` que contem 12 objetos, 1 para cada mês do ano.

Baseado na data da posição, eu queria recuperar a `FaixaPreco` em que se enquadra:

Pode ser assim, `dataPosicao >= dataInicial` da faixa.

```kotlin
data class Posicao(
    val id: Long? = null,
    var data: LocalDate? = null,
    var nome: String? = null
)
```

```kotlin
data class FaixaPreco(
    val id: Long? = null,
    var dataInicial: LocalDate,
    var taxaAa: BigDecimal? = null
)
```

```kotlin
val posicao = Posicao(1L, LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 13), "posição")
    
    
val faixas: MutableList<FaixaPreco> = mutableListOf();
faixas.add(FaixaPreco(1L, LocalDate.of(2021, 1, 12), BigDecimal("0.01")))
faixas.add(FaixaPreco(2L, LocalDate.of(2021, 2, 12), BigDecimal("0.03")))
faixas.add(FaixaPreco(3L, LocalDate.of(2021, 3, 12), BigDecimal("0.05")))
    
val faixaPreco = faixas.firstOrNull { posicao.data!!.isAfter(it.dataInicial) }
```

Comment: E qual é a dificuldade? Seu código me parece ok.

Comment: Com esse código ele está pegando todas as faixas que são depois da data da posição, no caso ele está pegando 2021/01/12 e 2021/02/12 e 2021/03/12, mesmo eu colocando firstOrNull, pensei em uma solução aqui agora que é ordenar esse Array pela data, pode ser que de certo!

Comment: O `firstOrNull` só retorna um elemento, nunca uma coleção.

Comment: Resolvido, obrigado pela atenção                                                                                                                                                                     val sorted = faixas.sortedBy { it.dataInicial }
val faixa = sorted.last { it.dataInicial!!.isBefore(posicao!!.data) || it.dataInicial!!.isEqual(posicao!!.data) }